# Parsing Python list into pandas.DataFrame with keywords

Tags: python, list, parsing, data-conversion

I have a list of countries that should turn into a DataFrame. Problem is that every country and the data is a sepparate word in the list. Example:

```
[
 'Viet',
 'Nam',
 '0',
 '12.3',
 '0',
 'Brunei',
 'Darussalam',
 '12',
 '1.1',
 '0',
 'Bosnia',
 'and',
 'Herzegovina',
 '2',
 '2.1',
 '0',
 'Not',
 'applicable',
 'Turkey',
 '4',
 '4.3',
 '0',
 'Only',
 'partial',
 'coverage'
...
]
```

How to convert this into:
    [
     ['Viet Nam', '0', '12.3', '0'],
     ['Brunei Darussalam', '12', '1.1', ...],
    ...
    ]
or `pd.DataFrame:

```
             country  coef1  coef2  grade
0           Viet Nam      0   12.3      0
1  Brunei Darussalam     12    1.1      0
```

**NOTE:** Some countries have one word like China, France or three or more words like Republic of Korea. Also, sometimes after this series of number there can be a remark.

Comment: Are the number of fields consistent? I.E. always 5 for a country?

Comment: Nope, it can be more or less like 'Bosnia',  'and',  'Herzegovina', or 'Tukey'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Where ***data_in*** is data you want to parse and ***countries*** is a list of all countries of the world

```
import pandas as pd
import re

countries = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia" ...]

data_in = [
    'Viet', 'Nam', '0', '12.3', '0', 'Brunei', 'Darussalam', '12', '1.1', '0', 'Bosnia', 'and', 'Herzegovina', '2', '2.1', '0', 'Not', 'applicable', 'Turkey', '4', '4.3', '0'
]

data_out = []

country = coef1 = coef2 = grade = []

def is_country(elem):
  isCountry = False
  for country in countries:
    if elem.lower() in country.lower():
      isCountry = True
      break
  return isCountry

def is_num(elem):
  if re.search(r'\d', elem) is not None:
    return True
  else:
    return False

idx = 0
while idx < (len(data_in)):
  elem = data_in[idx]
  country = ''
  elements = []
  is_country_name = False
  data_out_local = []
  if is_country(elem):
    #
    while (not is_num(elem) and idx < len(data_in)):
      country += elem + " "
      idx += 1
      elem = data_in[idx]
    while(is_num(elem) and idx < len(data_in)):
      elements.append(elem)
      idx += 1
      if idx < len(data_in):
        elem = data_in[idx]
    data_out_local.append(country)
    data_out_local.extend(elements)
    data_out.append(data_out_local)
  idx += 1


df = pd.DataFrame(data_out, columns=['country', 'coef1', 'coef1', 'grade'])
print(df)
```

pandas.DataFrame output:

```
                   country coef1 coef1 grade
0                Viet Nam      0  12.3     0
1  Bosnia and Herzegovina      2   2.1     0
2                  Turkey      4   4.3     0
```

> Nonstandard solution, but it works

Comment: This is good, but some countries have one word like China, France or three or more words like Republic of Korea. Also, sometimes after this series of number there can be a remark.
I was thinking to make a list of country names and then parse, but still not sure how.

Comment: Could you share a more detailed list with different type of data. What type of remark?

Comment: I added two more prominent examples for Turkey and Bosnia in the list

Comment: Your data set is very nonstandard, this makes it hard to parse. Unless to use its elements to search in a list with every country of the world to see if it is a part of name or is just a remark.

Comment: The solution was updated regarding new data you provided. Nonstandard solution, but it works.